# Share short link to comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, script-request

### 1. Request

It would be nice, if will be script for share short links to comments on Stack Exchange sites, not long links.

---

### 2. Justification

I found out, that links to comments [**may be short**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290576/326972). For example,

- **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512172/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8#comment622977_512172** — 496 characters.

is the same link as

- **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/622977** — 49 characters

Second link is more preferred because:

1. Some web forms has a limit the number of characters.

---

### 3. Desirable behavior

I open any page of any Stack Exchange site → near each comment I saw link, for example, `clipboard` → I click to `clipboard` → short link to comment will be transfer to my clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script that should work.  It is **untested** and unhosted at the moment. :

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange, Comment cleanup
// @description See stackapps.com/questions/7202/
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://*/review
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @version     0.5
// @history     0.5 Initial release, untested
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("a.comment-link", useShortLinkFormat);

function useShortLinkFormat (jNode) {
    var oldHref     = jNode.attr ("href");
    var commentNum  = oldHref.match (/.+?comment(\d+).+/);
    if (commentNum  &&  commentNum.length > 1) {
        var commentNum = commentNum[1];
        jNode.attr ("href", '/posts/comments/' + commentNum)
        jNode.append ('<small> sl</small>')
    }
}
```

Comment: Brock Adams, thanks for a script! If I hover my mouse to `sl`, I see short link. But if I click to `sl`, page reload for me, but short link not transfer to my clipboard. Windows 64-bit EN, Firefox 51.0.1. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Sorry, I slapped that script together quickly and forgot about your clipboard wish.  Until I add it, you can right-click the link and select `Copy Link Location` to get it to the clipboard.  ... Meanwhile, let me know if there are other issues.

Comment: @BrockAdams I recommend searching on google `copy to clibpoard javascript` and you will find some code to copy to clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, @smileycreations15. But I stopped work on this script because I had a plethora of higher priorities and because it appears to be of no interest to anyone outside the OP.  I'll probably revisit it now, though just for the sake of completeness.